# Grouping a column 'Time' by it's hour value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, pandas-groupby

I have a column with a Time column in H:M:S format

```
ColA    Time       Amount
a       10:32:01      10
b       09:10:56      10   
c       13:43:11      10
d       10:05:00      10
e       09:35:30      10
```

I'm only concerned about the hour value, i'd like to end up with a table like below:

```
Time       Amount
10:00:00      20
09:00:00      20   
13:00:00      10
```

I'm doing this:

```
df.groupby('Time')['Amount'].sum()
```

But this obviously groups exact matching Time values. I just need to group by the hour.

Comment: Isn't it more logical to make `13:43:11` to `14:00:00` and `10:32:01` to `11:00:00`?

Comment: Hmmm yes that is something I didn't think about, it could make a difference in what I'm doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the column `Time` as the index, and things become simple:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA":["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
                  "Time":["10:32:01", "09:10:56", "13:43:11", "10:05:00", "09:35:30"],
                  "Amount":[10,10,10,10,10]})

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

df.groupby(df.index.hour).sum()
```

and you get:

```
    Amount
Time    
9   20
10  20
13  10
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer by @sentence however in the mean time I found I could just do the following:

```
df.Time = [hour.split(':')[0] for hour in df.Time]
```

It works for my case however I don't know what implications that has should I need to do anything else.